# Error ssl_error_unknown_ca_alert Peer does not recognize and trust the CA that issued your certificate

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a problem. I become the error in the headline. I have a signed certificate from a recognized company. Now I want to create a second certificate.

I created the key with

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out example.abc.key
```

then the CSR-File with

```
openssl req -new -key example.abc.key -out example.abc.csr
```

and removed the passphrase with

```
openssl rsa -in example.abc.key -out example.abc.key
```

Now I created the certificate signed by the other certificate I become from the recognized company with

```
openssl x509 -req -in example.abc.csr -CA signed.certificate.crt -CAkey signed.certificate.key -out example.abc.crt
```

After all, I create the PKCS12-File

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in example.abc.crt -inkey example.abc.key -name "Example Client" -out example.abc.p12
```

If I call the website the webserver ask the client to identify and I can selected the imported certificate. The error in the headline appears and I didn't know how to solve it. I'm frustrated, because I googled, but didn't find anything which helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you got a signed certificate and you want to use it to sign another certificate. Since I'm pretty sure that you just got a normal certificate you might be able to sign another certificate, but this new certificate will not accepted by anybody. Only CA certificates can be used to successfully sign other certificates.

If this restriction would not be there then anybody could get a certificate for its own site (example.com) and then use it to sign a certificate for some other site like paypal.com. This would be indeed very bad if this would work.

Comment: You're right. This means if I got a normal certificate, I can sign another certificate, but the new one won't accepted by every client (browser) and the user become an error?

Comment: @Premox: yes, openssl let you use the certificate for signing but clients will not accept it when they validate the certificate issued by you.

Comment: Ok, another question for me to understand correctly: If I created a private key and a csr-file and I want to sign the certificate with my I got, is it issued by me?

Comment: @Premox: I don't really understand the question. But maybe you should make yourself more comfortable with the concepts involved, i.e. [certificate hierarchy](https://www.google.com/search?q=certificate+hierarchy), [trust chain](https://www.google.com/search?q=trust+chain) and [certificate agency](https://www.google.com/search?q=certificate+agency).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. They helped me a lot and I solved my problems