# Adding Payeezy FirstData self-signed certificate to server Trusted Store CA on Centos 7 with VestaCP

Tags: php, nginx, centos, certificate, vesta

I'm having an issue with setting up certificate on my **Centos 7** **VPS** that runs **VestaCP** with **Nginx** and **PHP-FPM** for a website that runs Wordrpress CMS via SSL (we have already signed and running GoDaddy certificate). Basically what I am doing is adding Payeezy FirstData certificate to a Wordpress with WooCommerce project using these steps:

1. Running this command from SSH
   `openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout 1234567key.pem -out 1234567req.pem -subj "/C=LV/O=domain.com/CN=1234567" -outform PEM`
   where **1234567** is Merchant ID
2. Signing the request at https://secureshop-test.firstdata.lv/keystore_.do using **1234567req.pem** file for test system and then getting the **ECOMM-test.pem** and **1234567.pem** files by as a response e-mail.
3. Running this command `openssl pkcs12 -export -in 1234567.pem -out 1234567keystore.p12 -certfile ECOMM-test.pem -inkey 1234567key.pem`
4. Running this command `openssl pkcs12 -in 1234567keystore.p12 -out 1234567keystore.pem`

After doing this I asked FirstData to add our VPS IP address to their allowed hosts.

By documentation and their support I've done everything right so far and all should work, but when I try to run sample transaction .php script I get this response:

> **startDMSAuth: Peer does not recognize and trust the CA that issued your certificate.**

Which in human language means - *your server does not trust the authority that signed this certificate. Please add it to Trusted Store Certificate Authority list* (something like that).

The problem is that I don't know how to do it (*add CA to Trusted Store CA list on Centos7 running VestaCP with Nginx and PHP-FPM*) and can't find proper documentation or tutorial how to do it so I was hoping someone here has had an experience with this and could explain me and others with the same issue how to do it.

Comment: Try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162475/error-ssl-error-unknown-ca-alert-peer-does-not-recognize-and-trust-the-ca-that-i#34163253

Comment: I've read this and lots of other Q&As here. The post that you shared is about a certificate that is SELF-signed, but in my case I need to send CSR to the Payeezy Firstdata for signing and then I get an e-mail with final parts for generating certificate keystore file.

Comment: @RicardsMucelans so do you just need to add a new root cert to your exsting ca? Is this a standard centos7 build etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here:
https://gist.github.com/oussemos/cf81d86a446544bfa9c92f3576306aff 
**Don't do line 403: <strike>`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect github.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem`</strike>**

In short:

1. Open SSH and run below commands as `sudo`
2. `update-ca-trust force-enable`
3. `update-ca-trust extract`
4. `cp certificate.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` (change `certificate.pem` to the certificate that you want to add
5. `update-ca-trust extract`